# How to use a macro variable to be lagged like a date in SAS

Tags: macros, sas

I'm using `SAS`. I have more `datesets`, one per month and I have to compute variations, means etc. considering more `datasets` (months) at the same step of the `macro` because for example for `VAR1` I have one value in the dataset of january (month x) and one value in the dataset of february (month x+1).

The `datasets` are named in this way: `xxxxxx_yearmonth` (for example yearmonth=201512 for december 2015)

So I have to create a `macro variable` called `yearmonth` that can be lagged for more months so I can recall them.

I thought to recall the datasets with the `macro variable` yearmonth and do: `yearmonth - 1 ... yearmonth - 2 ... yearmonth - n`. But there is a problem because if is january 2015 `yearmonth=201501` and `yearmonth-1=201500` and not `201412`. The fact is that `SAS` doesn't recognize yearmonth like a date but treat it like a simple number.

How can I manage this problem?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Convert the string to a date and use the `INTNX()` function.

```
%let current=201501;
%let prev=%sysfunc(intnx(month,%sysfunc(inputn(&current.01,yymmdd8)),-1),yymmn6);
%put &=prev;
```

Answer (score 0):

Try using `intnx` in combination with `sysfunc` and the format yymmn6.
Something like:

```
%let yearmonth1 = %sysfunc(intnx(month,%sysfunc(inputn(&yearmonth,yymmn6.)),-1),yymmn6.);
```

Or more simple the datastep Version (also better for looping through it):

```
data _null_;
do i = 1 to 6;
    monthid = put(intnx('month',input("&yearmonth",yymmn6.),-i),yymmn6.);
    call symput(cats('yearmonth',i),monthid);
end;
run;
```